# How can I add user to Gnu Gatekeeper?

Tags: voip

I've installed Gnu Gatekeeper from Debian wheezy repository.

And I can't figure out how I can add user account to Gnu Gatekeeper server to use it in Ekiga or NetMeeting? What I should write in /etc/gatekeeper.ini to it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add accounts. By default the GNU Gatekeeper will allow all user registrations. Just set Ekiga or Netmeeting the gatekeeper IP and thats it.

Later you can configure authentication to restrict who is allowed to register and eg. add database lookups for user accounts or restrict users by IP etc. See chapter [chapter 8](http://www.gnugk.org/gnugk-manual-8.html)  in the GnuGk manual.

There are sample configuration files in the etc/ directory in your download archive. Start with gnugk.ini and add switches from the manual as needed.

Comment: I forgot to write that I installed Gnugk from Debian wheezy repository. May be, it is not the same as if I would compile it by my self. First of all I try to use SimplePasswordAuth. And I got in Ekiga error in my language "Authentification failure". Now, I following by your advise and delete SimplePasswordAuth section. But nevertheless I got admissionReject rejectReason = callerNotRegistered <<null>> error. May be there some other setting in config file. Thank you for your attention!

Comment: That error means Ekiga tried to make a call before being registered (or the registration failed). Make sure you remove the whole [Gatekeeper::Auth] section.

Comment: Sorry, I'm newbie in Gnugk. I realised that I launched gnugk without gatekeeper.ini at all by `gnugk -ttt`. So it seems to use default params. And it still rejects the call with `rejectReason = callerNotRegistered <<null>>`. When I create account in Ekiga, I specify Name, Gatekeeper node (IP), login, password, delay. And without password it still can registers in Gatekeeper, but when I try to call, it throws error `rejectReason = calledPartyNotRegistered <<null>>`

Comment: If calls get rejected with calledPartyNotRegistered, it means the gatekeeper doesn't find the destination for your call. But I think you are probably better off subscribing to the GnuGk users mailinglist (link on gnugk.org) and discuss your issues there instead of in the comments here.